# Copyind data from oracle to azure blob storage through azure data factory

Tags: azure, dataset, azure-blob-storage, azure-data-factory

I have to copy data from oracle table to a csv file in azure blob. I used the copy activity component and add the proper configuration. But the problem is oracle data have some commas because of which the csv file generated does not contain proper data.Please help with this problem i am new to azure data factory  below is the link of my blob dataset properties.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/z7E4X.png

Comment: Check this article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/supported-file-formats-and-compression-codecs#text-format you can use the `quoteChar` property.

Comment: If you found an answer, take few minutes to post an answer :-)

Comment: yes found the anwer. There is property in advance tab in blob dataset called quote character . I have filled " as value in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below image will solve your problem.
There is a property in advance tab of blob dataset called quote character.
please refer the below image

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ItgWO.png

Answer (score 0):

Actually I need some information from you. What is the delimiter used in your CSV file. Is it comma or some other like pipe.

If you have used comma as a delimiter then you need to use the replace function to replace the comma which is there in your data to prevent it from being delimited.

Use the below code to replace:

***Replace(name, "," , " ")***

/*Here name is the column name*/

If the delimiter is pipe then the data might contain pipe. You need to use the REPLACE function in the similar way.

Regards,

Pratik